# Setting rootViewController crashes on iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8

It all worked OK in iOS 6 and 7. Without any change made now it is crashing in iOS 8.
Declared in AppDelegate.h:

```
IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
```

in AppDelegate.m: [application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions]:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:splitViewController];
```

It crashes here with the message EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2).

**Edit**: I am checking splitViewController's value, it is not nil.

Please share with me any info that could be relevant. Thanks!

Comment: check the value of splitViewController when you set it as the root view. Check it isn't nil?

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved itself. After restarting XCode 6, my app runs as expected. No more crashing.